# is it possible to use PyMongo in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to use a MongoDB Database from a Google App Engine service is that possible? How do I install the PyMongo driver on Google App Engine? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  Read the [Runtime Environment](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/overview.html) section.  On App Engine you'll have to use the [datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview.html), or a 'database service' you can access using HTTP calls.

You might want to check out [TyphoonAE](http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible because you don't have access to networks sockets in App Engine. As long as you cannot access the database via HTTP, it's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

The new [runtime environment section](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/runtime) says:

> an app cannot write data to the local file system or make arbitrary network connections.

I am not sure to which level this is still being enforced (seeing that it's 7 years since the question was asked and answered), but we at [Tam](https://tamhub.com) have successfully used the PyMongo driver in the standard Google App Engine Python runtime without issues. We simply followed the [official PyMongo tutorial](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html) and it worked out.